# FMX [Android] make multiple Labels bold

Tags: android, delphi, fonts, label, delphi-10.3-rio

I've got 5 labels on my form whose Fonts styles should all get the BOLD property added. I tried doing this using the code below but only Label2 gets bold and the rest still stays as it is at design time.

```pascal
  Sleep(350);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Label2.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label2.TextSettings.Font.Style +
        [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      Label2.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Gray;
    end);
  Sleep(350);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style +
        [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      Label3.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Gray;
    end);
  Sleep(350);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Label4.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label4.TextSettings.Font.Style +
        [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      Label4.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Gray;
    end);
  Sleep(350);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Label5.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label5.TextSettings.Font.Style +
        [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      Label5.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Gray;
    end);
  Sleep(350);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Label6.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label6.TextSettings.Font.Style +
        [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      Label6.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Gray;
    end);
  Sleep(350);
```

The colors change on each Label, but the Fonts aren't getting bold except for the first label which I try to get bold... this is confusing me. please help me.
I use Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition and an Android 10 Smartphone (Lineage 17.1)

Comment: Are you running the code above in an external thread or the main thread?

Comment: In an external Thread, thats why I synchronized it

Comment: Good, I just wanted to check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all labels, for which you want to manipulate the `Style` property, you need to remove the `Style` setting from `StyledSettings`.

(As the color change works, you already removed the `FontColor` setting from `StyledSettings`)

Actually, if you set any of these settings at design time, the IDE removes the corresponding `StyledSetting`. If you don't change any of these settings at design time, you must remove the corresponding `StyledSettings` before you can change the setting at runtime.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Sthe FontColor property was already false without changing anything, but now as I removed the Style Tag it works :)